# Parsec fails without error if reading from file

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I wrote a small parsec parser to read samples from a user supplied input string or an input file. It fails properly on wrong input with a useful error message if the input is provided as a semicolon separated string:

```
> readUncalC14String "test1,7444,37;6800,36;testA,testB,2000,222;test3,7750,40"
*** Exception: Error in parsing dates from string: (line 1, column 29):
unexpected "t"
expecting digit
```

But it fails silently for the input file `inputFile.txt` with identical entries:

```
test1,7444,37
6800,36
testA,testB,2000,222
test3,7750,40
```

```
> readUncalC14FromFile "inputFile.txt"
[UncalC14 "test1" 7444 37,UncalC14 "unknownSampleName" 6800 36]
```

Why is that and how can I make `readUncalC14FromFile` fail in a useful manner as well?

Here is a minimal subset of my code:

```
import qualified Text.Parsec                    as P
import qualified Text.Parsec.String             as P

data UncalC14 = UncalC14 String Int Int deriving Show

readUncalC14FromFile :: FilePath -> IO [UncalC14]
readUncalC14FromFile uncalFile = do
    s <- readFile uncalFile
    case P.runParser uncalC14SepByNewline () "" s of
        Left err -> error $ "Error in parsing dates from file: " ++ show err
        Right x -> return x
    where
        uncalC14SepByNewline :: P.Parser [UncalC14]
        uncalC14SepByNewline = P.endBy parseOneUncalC14 (P.newline <* P.spaces)

readUncalC14String :: String -> Either String [UncalC14]
readUncalC14String s = 
    case P.runParser uncalC14SepBySemicolon () "" s of
        Left err -> error $ "Error in parsing dates from string: " ++ show err
        Right x -> Right x
    where 
        uncalC14SepBySemicolon :: P.Parser [UncalC14]
        uncalC14SepBySemicolon = P.sepBy parseOneUncalC14 (P.char ';' <* P.spaces)

parseOneUncalC14 :: P.Parser UncalC14
parseOneUncalC14 = do
    P.try long P.<|> short
    where
        long = do
            name <- P.many (P.noneOf ",")
            _ <- P.oneOf ","
            mean <- read <$> P.many1 P.digit
            _ <- P.oneOf ","
            std <- read <$> P.many1 P.digit
            return (UncalC14 name mean std)
        short = do
            mean <- read <$> P.many1 P.digit
            _ <- P.oneOf ","
            std <- read <$> P.many1 P.digit
            return (UncalC14 "unknownSampleName" mean std)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is happening here is that a prefix of your input is a valid string. To force parsec to use the whole input you can use the `eof` parser:

```
uncalC14SepByNewline = P.endBy parseOneUncalC14 (P.newline <* P.spaces) <* P.eof
```

The reason that one works and the other doesn't is due to the difference between `sepBy` and `endBy`. Here is a simpler example:

```
sepTest, endTest :: String -> Either P.ParseError String
sepTest s = P.runParser (P.sepBy (P.char 'a') (P.char 'b')) () "" s
endTest s = P.runParser (P.endBy (P.char 'a') (P.char 'b')) () "" s
```

Here are some interesting examples:

```
ghci> sepTest "abababb"
Left (line 1, column 7):
unexpected "b"
expecting "a"

ghci> endTest "abababb"
Right "aaa"

ghci> sepTest "ababaa"
Right "aaa"

ghci> endTest "ababaa"
Left (line 1, column 6):
unexpected "a"
expecting "b"
```

As you can see both `sepBy` and `endBy` can fail silently, but `sepBy` fails silently if the prefix doesn't end in the separator `b` and `endBy` fails silently if the prefix doesn't end in the main parser `a`.

So you should use `eof` after both parsers if you want to make sure you read the whole file/string.

Comment: Brilliant! That solved the issue indeed. And I learned something new after spending an unreasonable time tonight trying to figure this out. Thank you very much!